# How to change the label text color when text filed is focused when more than one textfield used in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My requirement is I have 2 textfield widgets, when I click on first text field widget I need to change the label text color matching to cursor & border color. Same way when I click on 2nd text field, same behavior expected. How to achieve this.

Below is my code what I have tried so far:

```dart
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
              child: TextField(
                cursorColor: Color(0xFFD9A506),
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username',
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xFFD9A506), style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF919191)),
                  ),
                  labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF919191)),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  userName = value;
                  setState(() {
                    if (!userName.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty) {
                      isTextFiledFocus = true;
                    } else {
                      isTextFiledFocus = false;
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 38.0, left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
              child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Color(0xFFD9A506),
                  obscureText: isHidePassword,
                  enableSuggestions: false,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFD9A506),
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        //eye icon
                        color: Color(0xFF919191),
                        onPressed: () {
                          //for keyboard to hide
                          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                            currentFocus.unfocus();
                          }
                          //for keyboard to hide
                          setState(() {
                            isHidePassword = !isHidePassword;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(isHidePassword
                            ? Icons.visibility
                            : Icons.visibility_off)), //eye icon
                    enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF919191)),
                    ),
                    labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF919191)),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    password = value;
                    setState(() {
                      if (!userName.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty) {
                        isTextFiledFocus = true;
                      } else {
                        isTextFiledFocus = false;
                      }
                    });
                  }),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FocusNode` with listener to change the label color. We just need to update the UI when focus is changed. You can also change the label text the same way.

```dart
  final FocusNode focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode focusNode2 = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode1.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    focusNode2.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

And assign focuse node on `TextFiled`

```dart
TextField(
 cursorColor: Color(0xFFD9A506),
 focusNode: focusNode1,
 decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: focusNode1.hasFocus
          ? Color(0xFFD9A506)
          : Color(0xFF919191)),
  labelText: "UserName",
```

Do the same for next `TextFiled`.